# file_put_contents not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-put-contents

I try to upload something to my ubuntu server by file_put_contents (a converted base64-string as .jpg) with the following code :

```
file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data)));
```

And yes, all parameters are right, I double checked them. And I'm wondering why it is not working:

By the way: I try to upload it to a folder, one level higher then the folder, that is reachable by the url (but even when putting it directly in internet folder, it doesn't work either).

I thought about bad permissions, but even when changing permissions to 777 (which I know is very unsafe), it doesn't work.

I also don't get any errors in console.

Does anybody have an idea why this is not working?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `$filename`?

Comment: `$filename = "../userImgs/img1" `

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @AbraCadaver you mean, just put that code under my `file_put_contents();`? If yes, then this doesn't display any errors either. If not, where else should I put it?

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(../userImgs/img1pg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 37... but what do I have to change then? 
**Edit** Now, with 777 all it works, but this is very unsafe as I know....Which permissions should I give but have it still working?

Comment: `/var/www/html/test.php` is this the correct path? and you double checked if `www-data` (the apache user) can write there?

Comment: @XicoXperto that seems to be the problem, that the apache user can't write there, is there anyway to just allow this user writing, and have all others just reading?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't had the code there, but you can always do a `$ sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/html/` (still I advise you to make a folder for that kind of things and not the root of the project)

Comment: another topic is that regex doesn't look well formated, ill make a full response

Comment: Okay, but this doesn't change the privilieges of the user, does it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91659/discussion-between-user3375021-and-xicoxperto).

Comment: @user3375021 no, there you just change the group, take a look at my response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Folder Permissions

About the permissions for the folder where you're trying to save (`/var/www/html`) you can change the group of the folder and change the permissions so that the group can write as:

```
$ sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/html/
$ sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html
```

### Regex

`preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data)`

AFAIK the pattern **must** have the start and end slashes, I think you've confused the `/` with `#`, so it would look like

`/^data:image/\w+;base64,/i`

Still that slash after *image* will give you some problems in some versions, so escape it with a backslash

`/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/i`

I think this will do :)