# Ubuntu php file_put_contents does not create file

Tags: php

I have checked this massage board three times over looking for the answer.

[In PHP, why won't this write to test.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307319/in-php-why-wont-this-write-to-test-txt)

[file_put_contents not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001363/file-put-contents-not-working)

[file_put_contents not creating txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900719/file-put-contents-not-creating-txt-file)

And yes I have checked, checked and recheck file and folder permissions.

-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 3 Mar 14 16:01 fileMsgid.txt

I have tried 777 775 and 650 with no success.

The line of code is simple

```
    $msgId = 3;   
    file_put_contents('fileMsgid.txt', $msgId);
```

The Ubuntu system won't create the file or write content to the file.

This works fine on the Windows development server but when I move the code to the Linux production server, squat happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you write the absolute path of the file?

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Comment: what's the output of var_dump(file_put_contents('fileMsgid.txt', $msgId)); ?

Comment: You can try with `__DIR__ . '/fileMsgid.txt'` instead

Comment: Check please PHP version on your ubuntu server. Functions file_put_contents avaiable from version 5. It it very strange, but may be you use PHP 4 on your server.

Comment: Try to print out the current working directory: var_dump(getcwd());

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The PHP is 5.5. I have tried the absolute path and nothing happens. The var_dump yields the value of the variable. I will try the __DIR__. and get back with the results.

Comment: When I did the var_dump it returned bool(false). But it should return int 3 or whatever the number of digits in the number.

Comment: Gave the absolute path and now the file is written but it is still empty. Could it be the owner of the file is www-data but I see the same permission -rw-r--r-- for the file owner www-data.

Comment: Well, it started working. I added the fopen, fwrite and fclose functions to write the data to the file. The file_put_contents would create the file but not populate it. So, I added the other functions to get what I needed to work. Go figure!!